# In iOS, how to change launchscreen image according environment (dev, hom, prod)?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift3

I have a launchscreen with a image, so far working well.

But now I have 3 schemas: dev, hom and prod.

I would to know how to change the launch screen image according the schema selected at the build time?

**EDIT**

I have in mind two options, but I do not know which one is best:

Option 1: Create two storyboards and create a variable to set the name of the correct storyboard in the app delegate. This variable I will use in the Info.plist key (Launch screen interface file base name).

Option 2: Create two scenes at the Launchscreen.storyboard and programatically set the correct scene according the enviroment.

Comment: I think it is not possible because the Xcode user interface not providing this type of facility.

Comment: I think that at beast you can add your own splash screen right after the default launch screen to display your image

Comment: Each splash screen corresponds to an environment, so I should launch the correct splash. I have in mind two options, but I do not know which one is best. I edit the question to show these options.

Comment: There's a slightly tricky way to do this, which is to create a script in the Build Phase that checks the build configuration variable to update in Info.plist the name of the launch image/screen you want to use.

Answer (score 3):

Use targets, add a target for each environment, each target will have its own info.plist and you just set a different launch screen storyboards for each target , set it once in the relevant info.plist and you ready to select any target and run.

Comment: I had created 3 schemas, each for an environment (dev, hom, prod), because I need to load some variables according to the requested environment.
Now, I created a new ImageAsset for a given environment (hom).
How to configure when I request to build this environment load the correct asset?

Comment: Will I have to create two storyboards? Can not have a single storyboard and only change the images?

Answer (score 2):

Option 1 is viable. You might have missed out on some setting for the Storyboard.

1. Create a Storyboard for each of the launch screen e.g `LaunchStaging.storyboard, LaunchProduction.storyboard`
2. For each of the Storyboard, ensure that the setting under `Attributes inspector` **Is Initial View Controller** is checked
3. Also, ensure that the setting under `File inspector` **Use as Launch Screen** is checked
4. Under the xcode project's target, go into `Build Settings`
5. Add a new **User-Defined Setting** e.g `LAUNCH_SCREEN`
6. From the newly added setting, set the corresponding Storyboard's name as the value for each of the scheme, e.g `staging => LaunchStaging, production => LaunchProduction`
7. Inside `Info.plist`, under **Launch screen interface file base name**, set the value as **$(LAUNCH_SCREEN)**

This should allow you to have different launch screens for different schemes

Comment: This should be the selected answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your second option definitely won't work, since you cannot execute any code on a LaunchScreen and the LaunchScreen is displayed before any code could be executed (even in your `AppDelegate`), so you cannot change the LaunchScreen file in runtime.

Your first option is almost correct. Indeed a viable solution could be creating several Storyboards for the different launch screens, but you need to tweak the `Info.plist` file in a build script, you cannot do this in runtime either. Be aware that I haven' actually tested this method, but in theory it should work.

Comment: Use targets, add a target for each environment.

Comment: Thanks for the idea @OlegSherman that's an even better approach. Guess you should post it as an answer and take the credit for it.