# How to swap iOS splash page image based on build configuration in Xamarin Forms application

Tags: ios, forms, xamarin

I have a Xamarin forms application and I have requirement to change the iOS splash page image (.png) configured in the LauchScreen.storyboard file based on a build compilation symbol. (ie, If the build configuration symbol "TEST-ENVIRONMENT" is defined, then display image-1.png on the splash page otherwise use image-2.png).  I thought maybe I could swap images by specifying a command to copy the appropriate image file in the Pre-build event but since they are Embedded Resources, I don't see how it could be done.    I'm at a loss as to how I can do this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, I don't think you can change the image in the `LaunchScreen.storyboard` at run time.

You can't assign a custom class to `LaunchScreen.storyboard`.

When launch screen image is being displayed, your app is in the loading state and you **can't** execute any code at that point.

The way I recommend you to do is create two LauchScreen.storyboard files for different configuration symbol and before you build your project, choose the right LauchScreen.storyboard file to build.

Refer: [execute-code-in-launch-screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27642016/execute-code-in-launch-screen)

[in-ios-how-to-change-launchscreen-image-according-environment-dev-hom-prod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46075804/in-ios-how-to-change-launchscreen-image-according-environment-dev-hom-prod)